# Replacing values in a dataframe for given indices

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I want to add values to a dataframe from a few lists. The lists are:

```
car_list
milage_lists
avg_speeds
```

and a list of indices, `idx` (not sorted). I want to replace the value of all elements at indices `idx` with the values from the three lists. 
What I tried was:

```
    sec_idx = range(len(idx))
    for index, second_index in zip(idx, sec_idx):
        df.at[index,'col1'] = car_list[second_index]
        df.at[index,'col3'] = mileage_lists[second_index]
        df.at[index,'col5'] = avg_speeds[second_index]
```

however this just freezes. Any idea on how I can do this?

EDIT: Here is a minimal working example.

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2, 4, 7], [1, 3, 3, 6], [4, 3, 6, 6], [1, 2, 4, 7], [1, 3, 3, 6], [4, 3, 6, 6]], columns=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'])
idx = [1, 3]

car_values = [344, 626]
gas_values = [12321 , 124124]

for ix in range(2):
    df.at[idx[ix], 'A'] = car_values[ix]
    df.at[idx[ix], 'D'] = gas_values[ix]
```

The problem is this freezes for large datasets (60 000 rows).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick (allows you to specify the column headers):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2, 4, 7], [1, 3, 3, 6], [4, 3, 6, 6], [1, 2, 4, 7], [1, 3, 3, 6], [4, 3, 6, 6]], columns=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'])

indices = [1, 3]
car_values = [344, 626]
gas_values = [12321 , 124124]

for idx, i, j in zip(indices, car_values, gas_values):
    df['A'].iloc[idx] = i
    df['B'].iloc[idx] = j
```

Comment: You bet. FYI, if you are only overwriting a small number of columns in the `df`, then it will probably suffice to just strictly write them one by one in the loop for readability (as in my example above). If that number of columns begins to grow, then formulating a way to iterate through the columns as well will be more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

if you have a list with indices

```
idx_list = [idx1, idx2, idex3]
```

and a list of lists with values

```
values_list = [car_list, milage_lists, avg_speeds]
```

then you can use the following to iterate through the lists and indices will increasing the column number

```
column_names= ['A', 'B', 'C']
for idx, list, col in zip(idx_list, values_list, column_names):
    df.iloc[idx,col] = list
```

the indices dont need to be sorted

Comment: The problem is my columns are given by strings: 'A', 'C', 'D' or 'col1', 'col3' etc.. I need to be able to use the column labels.

Comment: This will throw an error because you are indexing into an empty DataFrame. Also, you are assuming that `index` is integral. Finally, there `list` is usually an undesirable variable name.

Comment: you can iterate through columns the exact same way you iterate everything else. I see you have a list with columns, columns=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'], so just add columns into the zip.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the following *vectorized* solution:

```
In [175]: df.loc[idx, ['A','D']] = np.column_stack((car_values, gas_values))

In [176]: df
Out[176]:
     A  B  C       D
0    1  2  4       7
1  344  3  3   12321
2    4  3  6       6
3  626  2  4  124124
4    1  3  3       6
5    4  3  6       6
```